# Fill in rows to get the same amount in each group after group by. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

My goal is to get the same number of rows for each group by group. Originally, after the group by would get something like this:

```
        count   mean    std      min    25%      50%     75%    max
X   Y                           
56  2   5       25200   21       0.0    20000.0 20000.0 26000.0 60000.0
    8   1.0     20000   NaN      20000  20000   20000   20000   20000.0
952 2   25.0    216132  239321   0      35000   93100   55000   650000.0
233 2   1.0     0       NaN      0      0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
335 2   9.0     853     60018   0.0     35000   98000   130000  150000.0
    6   11.0    3409    4943    0.0      0.0    0.0     7750.0  11000.0
```

And to meet my goal I should get the following.

```
        count   mean    std      min    25%      50%     75%    max
X   Y                           
56  1   0       0       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN      
    2   5       252 21       0.0    20000.0 20000.0 26000.0 60000.0
    3   0       0       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
    4   0       0       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
    5   0       0       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
    6   0       0       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
    7   0       0       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
    8   1.0     20000   NaN      20000  200 20000   20000   20000.0
952 1   0       0       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
    2   25.0    216132  239  0      35000   93100   55000   650000.0
    3   0       0       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
    4   0       0       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
    5   0       0       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
    6   0       0       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
    7   0       0       NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN     NaN    NaN
    8   1.0     0       NaN      0      0          0       0      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
#if need in second level only all unique values from all second levels
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.get_level_values('X').unique(),
                                  df.index.get_level_values('Y').unique()])
```

---

```
#if need range from 1 to 8 (1,2,3,..8)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.get_level_values('X').unique(),
                                  np.arange(1,9)])
```

---

```
#if need range starts with min and end max value of all levels
idx = df.index.get_level_values('Y')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.get_level_values('X').unique(),
                                  np.arange(idx.min(),idx.max())])


df = df.reindex(mux)
print (df)
```